# Multiplying rows by the user input?

Tags: python

I am trying to write a program that prompts the user to enter 2 numbers, for the row and columns. Then outputs it in a grid shape by the asterisk but within a `for` loop.

```
userrow = int(input("Enter the size of the row:"))
usercolumn = int(input("Enter the size of the column: "))

row = 0
column = 0

for row in ('*'):
    print(row * userrow)

    for column in ('*'):
        print(column * usercolumn )

#gridlayout = row * column
print("The grid layout is: ", row,  column)
```

Comment: Take a look at what `for row in ('*'):  print(row)` prints. Do you understand why it does that?

Answer (score 3):

I will first explain what your current code does, why it's wrong, and then how to rewrite the code.

```
for row in ('*'):
    print(row * userrow)

    for column in ('*'):
        print(column * usercolumn)
```

This iterates a variable named `row` through `'*'`. Since this is an iterable of size 1, it effectively does not loop. So your code is essentially:

```
row = '*'
print(row * userrow)
for column in '*':
    print(column * usercolumn)
```

The same can be said for the column:

```
row = '*'
print(row * userrow)
column = '*'
print(column * usercolumn)
```

This just prints `userrow` asterisks and then `usercolumn` asterisks. What you instead want to do is loop `userrow` times or `usercolumn` times:

```
for i in range(usercolumn):
    print('*' * userrow)
```

That would work, which prints `usercolumn` asterisks, `userrow` times. Alternatively, `print('\n'.join(['*'*usercolumn]*userrow))`.

Comment: Ah right, i wasn't 100% sure on what i was doing wrong so thank you for emphasizing.
I just tested it, really useful thanks :)

Comment: @Morph No problem! Glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

Hello would this do the work?? There is no need for 2 loops. also no point of making 2 same variables (row and userrow)

```
userrow = 2
usercolumn = 3

for i in range(0,usercolumn):
    print(userrow * '*')

print("The grid layout is: ", userrow,  usercolumn)
```

output:

```
**
**
**
The grid layout is:  2 3
```